# Force single select with Razor Select Tag Helper

Tags: asp.net-core, select, razor, razor-pages, .net-6.0

I'm Struggeling to find a solution to the following Problem:

My Razor-Page has a form with two `select`-elements, only one of which will be active (not `disabled`) at a time. Their values are associated to the same Property in my model.
I had to make my Property an Array, so I could access the value of both selects, despite one of them always being "null".

This has lead to my select being rendered with the "multiple" attribute in HTML. How can I get rid of this? I want it to be single select.

My selects:

```
<select asp-for=TätigkeitIds required onchange="this.form.submit()" disabled=@(Model.Erfassung.TätigkeitNavigation != null && Boolean.Equals(Model.Erfassung.TätigkeitNavigation.Abzurechnen, true))>
@{
    <option selected=@(Model.Erfassung.TätigkeitNavigation == null) value="">Bitte eine nicht abzurechnende Tätigkeit wählen</option>
    foreach(StammdatenTätigkeit Tätigkeit in await Model.GetTätigkeitenAsync(false))
    {
        <option selected="@(Model.Erfassung.TätigkeitNavigation != null && String.Equals(Tätigkeit.Id, Model.Erfassung.TätigkeitNavigation.Id))" value=@Tätigkeit.Id>@Tätigkeit.Name</option>
    }
}
</select>
```

```
<select asp-for=TätigkeitIds required onchange="this.form.submit()" disabled=@(Model.Erfassung.TätigkeitNavigation != null && Boolean.Equals(Model.Erfassung.TätigkeitNavigation.Abzurechnen, false))>
@{
    <option selected=@(Model.Erfassung.TätigkeitNavigation == null || Boolean.Equals(Model.Erfassung.TätigkeitNavigation.Abzurechnen, false))  value="">nicht abrech. Std.</option>
    foreach(StammdatenTätigkeit Tätigkeit in await Model.GetTätigkeitenAsync(true))
    {
        <option selected="@(Model.Erfassung.TätigkeitNavigation != null && String.Equals(Tätigkeit.Id, Model.Erfassung.TätigkeitNavigation.Id))" value=@Tätigkeit.Id>@Tätigkeit.Name</option>
    }
}
</select>
```

The Property:

```
[BindProperty(SupportsGet = false)]
public String[] TätigkeitIds { get; set; }
```

The rendered HTML:

```
<select required onchange="this.form.submit()" id="T_tigkeitIds" multiple="multiple" name="T&#xE4;tigkeitIds">
    <option value="" selected="selected">Bitte eine nicht abzurechnende Tätigkeit wählen</option>
    <option selected="selected" value="d58559ac-6601-4871-aff2-aa72982fd5cc">Schulung</option>
</select>
```

```
<select required onchange="this.form.submit()" disabled="disabled" id="T_tigkeitIds" multiple="multiple" name="T&#xE4;tigkeitIds">
    <option selected="selected" value="">nicht abrech. Std.</option>
    <option value="c2b8fd29-c85b-49c1-a2db-35b9fa9d11a0">PJ-Bearbeitung</option>
</select>
```

Essentially, I am looking for a way to either force the HTML-Select to appear without the `multiple`-attribute **or** to make my Property a normal String again and tell the framework to fill it with whichever input isn't `null`.

Comment: Easiest solution is don't use a tag helper if doing so gets in your way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [the comment from Mike Brind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70256908/force-single-select-with-razor-select-tag-helper?noredirect=1#comment124198133_70256908), I was able to solve my problem by simply deactivating the tag helpers for my two `select`-Tags like so:

```
<!select name="TätigkeitIds" required onchange="this.form.submit()" @(Model.Erfassung.TätigkeitNavigation != null && Boolean.Equals(Model.Erfassung.TätigkeitNavigation.Abzurechnen, false) ? "disabled" : "")>
@{
    <option selected=@(Model.Erfassung.TätigkeitNavigation == null || Boolean.Equals(Model.Erfassung.TätigkeitNavigation.Abzurechnen, false))  value="">nicht abrech. Std.</option>
    foreach(StammdatenTätigkeit Tätigkeit in await Model.GetTätigkeitenAsync(true))
    {
        <option selected="@(Model.Erfassung.TätigkeitNavigation != null && String.Equals(Tätigkeit.Id, Model.Erfassung.TätigkeitNavigation.Id))" value=@Tätigkeit.Id>@Tätigkeit.Name</option>
    }
}
</!select>
```